# Show specific data from a selected item in a listview (xamarin form)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin form for developing a mobile application, in the "user_page" I am showing in a ListView the last order of the user and I have added the possibility to select a specific order for getting more information about it.

This is my xaml code:

```
<ListView x:Name="Wash_list">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Clicked="OnMore" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
                              Text="More Info" />
                    <MenuItem Clicked="OnQR" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
                              Text="QR_Code" />
                    <!--IsDestructive="True"-->
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <StackLayout Padding="15,0">
                    <Label Text="{Binding washType}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And this is my C# code (I am stuck on it..):

```
async public void  OnMore(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    HttpClient _Client = new HttpClient();
    var content = await _Client.GetStringAsync(urlTrade);
    var get = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WashBuyData>>(content);

    var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
    for (i = 0; i <= get.Count ; i++)
        if (true)
            await DisplayAlert("About " + mi.CommandParameter, "Buy on: " + get[i].timestamp, "OK");    
}
```

So...what I want to do is showing specific info from the selected item, how I can do this?
I have tried to pick the text value or the id from the selected item for set my "i" param but without success...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So.. Add `ItemTapped="OnItemTapped"` in your ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="Wash_list"
          ItemTapped="OnItemTapped">
```

After, add on CodeBehind.

```
void OnItemTapped(Object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var dataItem = (YourModel)(e.Item);
}
```